# How to set Focus in field inside a form

Tags: jquery, jsf, primefaces

I have this code:

```
 <script>
            function teste() {
                $("#firstname").focus();
            }
            ;
        </script>
        <br/>
        <hr/>
        <h:form id="form">
            <p:panel header="New User" id="pnl">
                <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                    <p:outputLabel for="firstname" value="Firstname: *" />
                    <p:inputText id="firstname" required="true" />

                    <p:outputLabel for="surname" value="Surname: *" />
                    <p:inputText id="surname" required="true" onclick="teste();" />
                </h:panelGrid>
            </p:panel>

            <p:commandButton value="Submit" update="pnl" oncomplete="teste();"/>
            <br/>
        </h:form>
```

I'm trying to set the focus of a field after the execution of an action, but when the component form exists, It does not work. When I remove the form component, the focus works. The problem is that I need to focus.
Anyone know how to solve and / or because of it?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean: "but when the component form exists, it does September When I remove the form component, the focus works. The problem is that I need to focus"  ???  What you need to focus?

Comment: but when the component form exists, It does not work. SOrry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`h:form` is a `UINamingContainer`, so its ID is prepended to the elements inside. Try the following:

```
function teste() {
    $("#form\\:firstname").focus();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the right answer indicates, that `h:form` is a `UINamingContainer`.

Here's another built-in approach

```
function teste() {
   PrimeFaces.focus('form:firstname');
}
```